# Можно ли задать параметры функции с условиями в Python

Tags: python

Всем привет, подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли задать в Python в функции параметры с условием, например, так:

```
 def show_my_drink(self, a>0:int):
        pass
```

Функция должна принимать целое положительное число. Условие a>0 приведено с ошибкой, но можно ли как-то это реализовать?

Comment: И всё же нужен какой-то контекст: кто будет вызывать эту функцию и что должно происходить, если придёт неправильный параметр.

Answer (score 6):

Обычно это делается так - проверяете значение переданного параметра в функции и выбрасываете исключение `ValueError` если значение ошибочное.

Пример:

```
def show_my_drink(a: int) -> None:
    if a <= 0 or not isinstance(a, int):
        raise ValueError(f"expecting positive integer in parameter [a], got: {a}")
    ...
```

Comment: MaxU, а если использовать @contract(a = 'int,>=0') из библиотеки contract?

Comment: @chernyahovsky2010, можно, конечно использовать дополнительные модули для этого, но надо для начала определиться что является для вас меньшим злом - использование дополнительных модулей и код, который не все Python программисты смогут понять или более раздутый код )

Answer (score 2):

> Функция должна принимать целое положительное число.

А что должно произойти если будет передано не целое положительное число? Исключение?
Тогда как вариант:

```
def show_my_drink(self, a):
    assert type(a)==int and a>=0, '"a" должно быть целое положительное число'
    pass
```

Comment: `type(a)==int` -> `isinstance(a, int)`

Comment: `a >= 0` -> `a > 0`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy для `a=True` `type(a)==int` -> `False` , `isinstance(a, int)` -> `True`

Comment: С точки зрения Питона `True` - целое положительное число. Странно, конечно, но так исторически сложилось. И это не сложно поправить в коде, проверив  `bool` отдельно. А вот проверка типа по полному совпадению не рекомендована. Вдруг вы захотите унаследоваться от `int`? Примеры такого наследования есть.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно в параметрах функции используются лишь *переменные*, не предполагающие каких-либо выражений типа суммирования, сравнения или прочего. Если же Вы хотите провести сравнение определённой переменной, то Вы можете сначала ввести её как параметр функции, а затем, в теле этой же функции, производить необходимые вычисления:

```py
def show_my_drink(self, a:int):
    if a <= 0:
        return
    // остальной код
```

Comment: все конечно зависит от конкретной задачи, но в общем случае я бы не стал __молча__ выходить из функции. Лучше в таком случае выбрасывать сообщение об ошибке или хотя бы предупреждение (`warning`)